# chi-squared test vs fisher's test vs ... => highly unbalanced length frequency data

Tags: r, t-test, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I would like to statistically verify if two distributions are identical. Basically, the first distribution is a length frequency distribution from a large population ("population"). The second is the length frequency distribution of individuals of this population that have been eaten by a predator ("consumed"). Consequently, I have a really high sample size for the population, and a rather small one for the consumed species. Also, the counts for population are high because data is weighted because of the sampling design, thus values are not actual counts.

For example:

```
structure(list(length = c(26, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.5, 31, 31.5, 32, 32.5, 33, 33.5, 34, 34.5, 35), population = c(1,  0, 0, 8, 351, 3162, 20688, 43775, 35189, 20615, 9628, 3454, 1484,  512, 236, 130, 28), consumed = c(0, 4, 10, 12, 12, 19, 39, 9,  2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("length", "population",  "consumed"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also, I would like to repeat the test for multiple species and over multiple years. During some years predators only eat the smallest/largest individuals, giving zero's for the largest/smallest lengths.

Given that my data is binned and I have always some cells with zero or low numbers (<5), what test should I use? I tried Fisher's, but here I get a warning saying that my numbers are too large (`FEXACT error 40. Out of workspace.`). Chi-square on the other hand posses a problem because of the low numbers, and my measurements aren't fine enough to use a kolmogorov smirnov test. A t-test is for normal data, and I have mostly gamma or binomial distributions.

How I am to know which test to use, or am I missing out on another one or something basic (like, I should standardize my data)?

Thanks